# How to assign the lastest terms and condtions to users upon sign in in a djanog project

Tags: python, django

I have the following model for the terms and conditions:

```
class TermsAndConditions(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Terms and conditions, last modified on {self.date_modified}'

class UserAgreement(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    agreed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    agreed_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    terms_and_conditions = models.ForeignKey(TermsAndConditions, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Agreement for user {self.user.username}'
```

I have the following views:

```
@login_required
def show_terms_and_conditions(request):
    try:
        user_agreement = UserAgreement.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except UserAgreement.DoesNotExist:
        user_agreement = UserAgreement.objects.create(user=request.user)
    terms_and_conditions = user_agreement.terms_and_conditions

    return render(request, 'tac/termsandconditions.html', {'terms_and_conditions': terms_and_conditions})
@login_required
def agree(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_agreement = UserAgreement.objects.get(user=request.user)
        user_agreement.agreed = True
        user_agreement.save()
        return redirect(reverse('........'))
    else:
        return redirect(reverse('.......'))
```

My objective to to assign the latest terms and conditions to every user who signs in and if it is not agreed then to show

here is what I tried

```
# @login_required
# def show_terms_and_conditions(request):
#     latest_tac = TermsAndConditions.objects.latest('date_modified')
#     user_agreement, created = UserAgreement.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, terms_and_conditions=latest_tac)
#     if created:
#         # If the user agreement was created in this request, set `agreed` to False and update the `agreed_at` field
#         user_agreement.agreed = False
#         user_agreement.agreed_at = timezone.now()
#         user_agreement.save()
#     terms_and_conditions = user_agreement.terms_and_conditions
# 
#     return render(request, 'tac/termsandconditions.html', {'terms_and_conditions': terms_and_conditions, 'user_agreement': user_agreement})
```

The reason I am doing this is because I keep getting
`NOT NULL constraint failed: tac_useragreement.terms_and_conditions_id`

Here is the traceback:

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: tac_useragreement.terms_and_conditions_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 142, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\my_gym\views.py", line 61, in get
    user_agreement = UserAgreement.objects.create(user=request.user)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 671, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 812, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 863, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1006, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1047, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1790, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1660, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: tac_useragreement.terms_and_conditions_id
[10/Feb/2023 20:41:47] "GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 500 177365
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not saving your terms and conditions while creating the `UserAgreement` Object.

```py
@login_required
def show_terms_and_conditions(request):
    try:
        user_agreement = UserAgreement.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except UserAgreement.DoesNotExist:
        user_agreement = UserAgreement.objects.create(user=request.user)
    terms_and_conditions = user_agreement.terms_and_conditions

    return render(request, 'tac/termsandconditions.html', {'terms_and_conditions': terms_and_conditions})
```

Should include

```py
....
except UserAgreement.DoesNotExist:
    # get your terms and conditions based on your criteria, pk is an example
    terms_and_conditions = TermsAndConditions.objects.get(pk=1)
    user_agreement = UserAgreement.objects.create(user=request.user, terms_and_conditions=terms_and_conditions)
```

Comment: I got the same error I will add the Traceback

Comment: Your traceback still shows that you are creating the user agreement without the terms and conditions. `File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\my_gym\views.py", line 61, in get 
user_agreement = UserAgreement.objects.create(user=request.user)`